# PHP DirectoryIterator and .DS_Store File

Tags: php, directory, dotfiles

I have a local XAMP install on my Mac. I have this code:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('test') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot() && $fileInfo->getBasename() !== '.DS_Store') {
        continue;
    }

    $xmlFile = "test/" . $fileInfo->getFilename() . "/content.xml";

    if (file_exists($xmlFile)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
        foreach ($xml->infos as $infos) {
            echo "<li><a href='#tab_3' data-toggle='tab'>$infos->bezeichnung</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error that says that the file `.DS_Store` cannot be opened. I thought my code filtered out the `.DS_Store` directory. It's clear that this file cannot be opened. It is a mac specific folder.

Answer (score 4):

Your filter is saying "if it is a dot file and it is not `.DS_Store`, skip it" which is the opposite of what I believe you want. Try this:

```
if ($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->getBasename() === '.DS_Store') {
    continue;
}
```

Which says "if it is a dot file (`.` or `..`) or it is `.DS_Store`, skip it."

Comment: Perhaps this was intended to be an `||` logical or, instead of and, to filter all of `.`  , `..` , and `.DS_Store`.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

`.DS_Store` is a file, not a folder.

Your code is inappropriately assuming that anything returned by the directory iterator will be a folder and looking for a `content.xml` file inside it; this fails for regular files. `.DS_Store` happens to be a file, but the same issue would arise with any other file which happened to be in this directory.

Use [the `isdir` method of DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdir.php) to check whether the current item is a directory before trying to open files within it. Once you do this, you won't need a special case for `.DS_Store`.